# Upgrading gradle to 6.0 requires ivy.xml and pom files

Tags: node.js, gradle, gulp

Trying to upgrade to gradle 6 but it seems to be backward incompatible with 5.0. Some dependencies are missing `.pom` and `ivy.xml` files. For example, we are using gulp plugin for one of our legacy app, and upgrading to 6.0 fails with the following error:

```
2019-12-31T13:04:34.590+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
2019-12-31T13:04:34.590+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on root.1
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':foo:nodeSetup'.
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':foo:detachedConfiguration1'.
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find org.nodejs:node:7.5.0.
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Searched in the following locations:
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]        - https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.5.0/ivy.xml
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :foo
2019-12-31T13:04:34.591+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2019-12-31T13:04:34.592+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2019-12-31T13:04:34.592+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2019-12-31T13:04:34.592+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2019-12-31T13:04:34.592+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2019-12-31T13:04:34.592+0100 [WARN] [org.gradle.internal.featurelifecycle.LoggingDeprecatedFeatureHandler] 
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

### Update

Looks like it is the same issue as https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/issues/351

Comment: And if you read the first comment on this issue, you'll find a fork of this plugin, which is compatible with gradle 6.

Comment: Jepp, looking into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the forked version of the plugin, i.e. changing the build script from:

```
plugins {
   id 'com.moowork.gulp' version '1.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.moowork.gulp'
```

TO:

```
plugins {
   id "com.github.node-gradle.gulp" version "1.3.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.gulp'
```